# How to delete a recursive array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

Suppose I had a class declared as such so that it held an array of pointers to children of its class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    MyClass** children;
    MyClass(int size)
    {
        if(size != 0)
        {
            children = new MyClass*[8];
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                children[i] = new MyClass(size - 1);
            }
        }
        else
            children = nullptr;
    }
    ~MyClass()
    { 
        if(children != NULL)
        {
            delete children[0];
            delete children[1];
            delete children[2];
            delete children[3];
            delete children[4];
            delete children[5];
            delete children[6];
            delete children[7];
        }
        delete [] children;
    }
}
```

Does my destructor properly kickstart a recursive deleting of all the children? If not, how do I properly do this?

Comment: You don't need to `delete` things you haven't `new`ed.

Comment: It could be simplified with a loop. Or better yet an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (if you want a compile-time fixed number of elements) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (if you might want to dynamically resize the collection). Also note, don't use *pointers* in the array or vector, use *instances* instead. All that will make it so you don't even *need* a destructor.

Comment: What if there were 1000 children?   You would write 1000 lines of `delete`?  Of course you wouldn't, even if you actually `new`-ed them (which you really haven't done).  There are things such as `for` loops in C++ (better yet, drop all of this and use container classes and/or smart pointers).

Comment: Well normally I would use a loop but I felt like writing it out because in my case it will always be 8.

Comment: *Does my destructor properly kickstart a recursive deleting of all the children?* Yes.

Comment: BTW, you need to initialize `children` to `nullptr` when `size` is equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks I'll fix that